Computation behind intuition of most "likely" sampled points from uniform distribution
If I am given N points for a univariate uniform distribution, I assume in expectation that the positions of these points to be at the values of $x_i=\frac{i}{N+1}$ for the $i^{th}$ largest value. This intuition comes from the fact that I think the points should be evenly spaced from each other and is backed up by the the computation of the order statistic.
When I extend this to the multivariate case, my intuition still stays a bit in check. Given $N^2$ points in two dimensions, my intuition tells me that in expectation the points should lie on $(\frac{i}{N+1},\frac{k}{N+1})$ for the $i^{th}$ largest point in the first dimension and $k^{th}$ largest point in the second dimension. I am not sure if this intuition is correct and furthermore am not sure how to compute that this is a reasonable thing to believe. Does anyone else have a similar intuition and proof to back up the belief? And how can this be extended to higher dimensions and points that don't easily make "grids" within each dimension (i.e. $n$ in $1$ dimension, $n^2$ in $2$ dimensions, etc.)

It looks like you're talking about the distribution of order statistics. As the Wikipedia article says, for $n$ iid uniform random variables on $(0, 1)$, the $k$th order statistic is distributed as $U_{(k)} \sim \mathrm{Beta}(k, n+1-k)$, whose expected value is indeed $\frac{k}{n+1}$.
